# Plausable deniablity / steganography in radio transmission

Tags: radio, security, encryption

Normally in a wartime scenario etc. strict radio silence is observed to prevent the enemy from evesdropping on your transmissions.

Encryption solves a part of the problem. Now the enemy cannot decipher your messages but can still know that you are transmitting.

I am wondering is there a way (say) by using a already noisy or crowded channel to transmit without any lay observer not being able to tell that you are transmitting unless he happens to know some secret about the way you are transmitting (e.g. timing info, hopping info etc.)

In essence something like Steganography but over a radio channel. e.g. Something like what TrueCrypt etc. can do on a hard drive's hidden partition. Except the person who knows the data exists there everyone would think on examination that the underlying bits are random.

Comment: Well, random bits are random bits - if they traced the transmission back to you, you're busted.

Comment: @rdtsc I guess the point would be adding just enough input to an already crowded channel so that no one could tell you were transmitting?

Comment: You mean spread spectrum?

Comment: I don't think it would matter - if they triangulated *any* kind of RF transmission to your location, then you'd be suspect. Even if spread spectrum were used, all it would take is one bit sampled from three simultaneous receivers for triangulation.

Comment: @rdtsc So essentially there's no analog of the way you can implement steganography on a hard disk for over the air channels? i.e. Radio Silence is here to stay.

Comment: Another idea (speculation) was to transmit in such subliminal amounts spread across so many narrow frequency slices in tiny bursts that it would be computationally non feasible somehow for an adversary to detect that you were transmitting at all. Perhaps because there's too many places to look at for too short bursts. i.e. To cover them all you'd need an astronomical sampling rate?

Comment: Encryption and spread-spectrum can make it practically impossible to *decipher* a transmission, but any transmission can be detected, which inherently eliminates plausible deniability. TrueCrypt's plausible deniability lies in the encryption strength used - a disk could be scanned for years with no evidence uncovered - but detecting any part of an RF transmission is evidence in itself.

Comment: @rdtsc I see what your saying.  I guess what I meant is (don't know if this makes sense) can one RF transmit at a strength / burst / slice that its practically impossible to detect that you are transmitting at all (unless the detector knows a shared secret)?

Comment: An alternative approach is to encode your messages on a higher level protocol on a standard channel, for example code words and trigger phrases in a public FM transmission. There is a reason for Voice of America's monstrous transmitters all over the world and it is not just freedom propaganda.

Comment: @LiorBilia Very interesting. Is there hint / rumor that VoA is / has been used for this sort of purpose?

Comment: Heh, you will have to find it yourself. The net is full of theories regarding them.

Comment: Long wave radio transmissions in the UK had phase encoded data to activate radio teleswitches on electricity meters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Which Stack Exchange site do you think is more appropriate for this then? I assumed RF / spread spectrum / freq. hopping etc. all fall fairly under the domain of Electronics SE. In any case, the answers I've received have been very helpful, of excellent quality  and definitely Electronics heavy.

Comment: @Andyaka Could a smart subscriber fool his meter into moving into a lower tariff mode by broadcasting a rouge signal from close to the meter stronger (locally) than the BBC signal?

Comment: @curious_cat the encrypted data transmission was never cracked as far as I remember - several different companies were all using the same chip but the chip "internal" information was protected by CCL (Cambridge Consultants Limited) who also designed it.

Comment: @Andyaka Impressive for an 1980's project. My naive thought was that any consumer grade device security that was designed in the '80s was kiddie hacker material for today (e.g. a lot of the metro rail cards)

Comment: @curious_cat there is an encryption technique from the 19C that is still the best & is virtually uncrackable. Age hasn't got anything to do with it, just the resolve of those that implement it

Answer (score 5):

Spread spectrum does this: -

[image]

The power spectral density of a transmission of direct sequence spread spectrum (DSSS) remains below a certain "noise level" (as shown in the diagram above). As will be shown later in this answer, due to DSSS's "processing gain", the actual received power level can be below the receiver's noise threshold across a large range of distances from the transmitter. This makes a transmission quite difficult to detect unless you have a matching receiver and you know the "code sequence" used in the transmission.

Because many individual low power "carriers" are simultaneously generated, there can be a negative SNR at any point in the spectrum but, the sheer multiplicity of simultaneous "carriers" means that a receiver can operate with a decent headroom of SNR. The receiver HAS to know or be able to learn the code sequence. The term "carriers" is not quite correct but for anyone not familiar with DSSS it's still a useful analogy.

This is a nice introduction: [Spread Spectrum Steganography](http://cs.uccs.edu/~cs591/studentproj/projF2005/sasummer/doc/SpreadSpectrum1.ppt)

> Encryption solves a part of the problem. Now the enemy cannot decipher
>   your messages but can still know that you are transmitting.

If the "enemy" is close enough to detect the spectrum above the noise thresholds then they are likely to know where you are by visual means. See [THIS](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjrkM2FzP7KAhWJzxQKHWFHBDkQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.ee.ethz.ch%2F~lfranck%2Fmuntwyler-wons12.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGuvP3nUVUESH5Ic61N6O60dLmNJA&sig2=fBFceyKXuPK4nGaAQPdBkA&cad=rja) for another good article that explains how many spreading frequencies are needed to get the transmission level progressively lower than the thermal noise of a typical receiver.

---

**EDIT**

Here's a basic and much simplified example. Let's say you have a payload data rate of 1 kbps and your code rate runs at 1024 x the payload rate. This will give you a processing gain of 30 dB when you receive the signal.

*FYI processing gain = 10log(PN codes per payload bit)*

Let's say you transmit 1 watt (30dBm) at nominally 1 GHz. If this transmission is "spread", the nominal power in an equivalent bandwidth of the unspread data is 30 dB lower (1 milli watt).

Next, the free-field theoretical received signal power at various distances (based on the Friis link loss equation) is: -

- 1 km Rx power is -92.4 dBm
- 10 km Rx power is -112.4 dBm
- 20 km Rx power is -118.4 dBm
- 40 km Rx power is -124.4 dBm

The above numbers assume an isotropic antenna i.e. power is transmitted in all directions. This doesn't effect the overall conclusion if any other antenna type were used.

A plain ordinary radio receiver requires a signal power at its antenna that is determined by the bandwidth of the transmission. A commonly used formula is *required received signal strength is -154 dBm + 10log(bit rate)*

The bit rate in the formula above is 1kbps x 1024 i.e. the "spread" bit rate. Therefore, a plain ordinary receiver needs -94 dBm to fully pick up the spread transmission. This means that a plain ordinary receiver is not going to detect any transmission further away from the source of transmission than about 1 km - it'll be in the noise at a greater distance.

However, a spread spectrum receiver can use its process gain (30 dB) to still receive the signal at distances up to nearly 40 km away.

It's never as clear cut as this with radio but on a good day, you should be able to receive the signal quite easily at many times the distance of a "non-code-aligned" receiver.

Comment: THIS was a cool paper

Comment: @Autistic which one?

Comment: The one that went to a lot of trouble to run with 1% error on a neg 2.7 db carrier to noise ratio at the reciever input terminals

Answer (score 2):

THe military uses Frequency hopping to compliment their encryption & help mitigate jamming

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-hopping_spread_spectrum

> Spread-spectrum signals are highly resistant to deliberate jamming,
>   unless the adversary has knowledge of the spreading characteristics.
>   Military radios use cryptographic techniques to generate the channel
>   sequence under the control of a secret Transmission Security Key
>   (TRANSEC) that the sender and receiver share in advance.
>
> By itself, frequency hopping provides only limited protection against
>   eavesdropping and jamming. Most modern military frequency hopping
>   radios also employ separate encryption devices such as the KY-57. U.S.
>   military radios that use frequency hopping include the JTIDS/MIDS
>   family, HAVE QUICK and SINCGARS

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowman_(communications_system)

> The Bowman HF frequency-hopping radios, of which 10,800 examples were
>   supplied is designated UK/PRC325 in its basic 20 W manpack form and
>   UK/VRC328/9 in its 100 W high-power and co-sited vehicular
>   configurations. Essentially a UK equivalent of the US AN/PRC-150, it
>   has had the proprietary Harris Citadel encryption from the original
>   RF-5800H replaced with UK Type 1 (Pritchel) encryption and frequency
>   hopping waveform. The Falcon II's original dual-band HF/VHF frequency
>   range (1.6-60 MHz) has been narrowed to the 1.6-30 MHz (HF) band.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "It would be *incredibly* hard/expensive.

Yes, you theoretically *could* transmit at a low enough power, with a pseudorandom-enough modulation, over a strong enough, uninterrupted 'background signal' to transmit a radio signal that *might* go undetected by the 'uninitiated.'

However, there are a limited supply of transmissions that are powerful enough & with predictable enough modulation to use as your 'background signal,' and this would only be feasible assuming that no 'enemy' got close enough to your transmitter for your transmission to have a higher amplitude than the pre-existing signal you're 'piggybacking on.'

Comment: Thanks. But yet not too hard / expensive for a state power perhaps?

Comment: Given a national government-type budget, it would be possible, yes. As to whether or not it would be practical enough/effective enough for any real use; I highly doubt that it would be worth the expense, due to the drawbacks you would encounter re: limited transmission range, ease of 'enemies' finding the frequency you're re-modulating on (due to low number of suitable frequencies to shoose from), and the 'proximity effect' whereby a nearby 'enemy' receiver could detect even your low output power as a stronger signal that the one you're using to cover it.